# Convert System.DayOfWeek into Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDaysOfWeek

Tags: c#, outlook-api

Is there a possibility to directly convert a value of [System.DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2) into a value of [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDaysOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.oldaysofweek?view=outlook-pia). Something like:

```
var day = DayOfWeek.Friday;
OlDaysOfWeek days = ConvertToDaysOfWeek(day);
```

Comment: There's no direct conversion, but you can write one, probably using a `switch` statement.

Comment: From your links it looks like the integer values behind the enums are different. I would write my own conversion method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var olDay = (OlDaysOfWeek) Enum.Parse(typeof(OlDaysOfWeek), $"ol{systemDay}");
```

Comment: Clever.  Bonus points if you wrap it in extensions methods for converting in both directions.

Comment: Bonus points if you can do this without string manipulation which is very slow.

Comment: @DavidG I thought the same thing at first too, but it's already going through a com interop layer.  I doubt the string manipulation is the bottle-neck.

Comment: Extra note:  You don't need to call `ToString()` on objects embedded in a string interpolation.  It's implicit.

Comment: @DavidG conversion by value is less safe

Answer (score 2):

To do this without using string manipulation, here's an option:

```
public OlDaysOfWeek ConvertToDaysOfWeek(DayOfWeek day)
{
    return (OlDaysOfWeek)Math.Pow(2, (int)day); 
}
```

Comment: This is the most terse form of conversion, good call o `Math.Pow`

Answer (score 1):

A simple switch statement would probably be most performant:

```
public OlDaysOfWeek ConvertToDaysOfWeek(DayOfWeek day)
{
  switch (day)
  {
    case DayOfWeek.Monday: return OlDaysOfWeek.olMonday;
    case DayOfWeek.Tuesday: return OlDaysOfWeek.olTuesday;
    case DayOfWeek.Wednesday: return OlDaysOfWeek.olWednesday;
    case DayOfWeek.Thursday: return OlDaysOfWeek.olThursday;
    case DayOfWeek.Friday: return OlDaysOfWeek.olFriday;
    case DayOfWeek.Saturday: return OlDaysOfWeek.olSaturday;
    case DayOfWeek.Sunday: return OlDaysOfWeek.olSunday;
    default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("What day is this?", "day");
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could probably parse the value and return the mapped value based on the enum value name.

```
public OlDaysOfWeek ConvertToDaysOfWeek(DayOfWeek day)
{
  return (OlDaysOfWeek) Enum.Parse(typeof(OlDaysOfWeek), "ol" + day.ToString());
}
```

The `OlDaysOfWeek` enum utilises a power-of-2 sequence, which is typically used when combining values as bitwise flags. `DaysOfWeek` has a simple linear sequence reflected as 0-6 - this is why you can't compare using the backing `int` value

Comment: Not quite right in your last paragraph, both enums use Sunday as the first day.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the following solution. Thanks for the hints.

```
public static OlDaysOfWeek AsDaysOfWeek(this DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    return (OlDaysOfWeek)(1 << (int)dayOfWeek);
}
```

To be used like this:

```
var day = DayOfWeek.Friday;
OlDaysOfWeek days = day.AsDaysOfWeek();
```

Additionally these are the unit tests in NUnit for the method:

```
[TestCase(DayOfWeek.Monday, OlDaysOfWeek.olMonday)]
[TestCase(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, OlDaysOfWeek.olTuesday)]
[TestCase(DayOfWeek.Wednesday, OlDaysOfWeek.olWednesday)]
[TestCase(DayOfWeek.Thursday, OlDaysOfWeek.olThursday)]
[TestCase(DayOfWeek.Friday, OlDaysOfWeek.olFriday)]
[TestCase(DayOfWeek.Saturday, OlDaysOfWeek.olSaturday)]
[TestCase(DayOfWeek.Sunday, OlDaysOfWeek.olSunday)]
public void AsDaysOfWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, OlDaysOfWeek expectedResult)
{
    var result = dayOfWeek.AsDaysOfWeek();

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
}
```

Comment: Did you find this answer online?

Comment: Note that you will have problems if any of the enumeration options change value.

Comment: "Additionally these are the unit tests" - you forgot the tests for out-of-range enum values :)

Comment: @StanislavMolchanovsky If microsoft changes the enumeration values, the most likely result is that *every* program using Outlook interop will have problems.  That would be a public interface change.  That's not something MS does lightly.

Comment: @BradleyUffner you are right, it is unlikely. But when choosing a solution it is necessary to consider all its pros and cons :)